# 'function' object has no attribute 'pprint'

Tags: python, django

I got this error when trying to print an object using `pprint.pprint(object)`

I imported `from pprint import pprint`....

```
'function' object has no attribute 'pprint'
```

My code:

```
output = ', '.join([ pprint.pprint(p) for p in people_list])
    return HttpResponse (output)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the traceback?

Comment: `import pprint` before when you use that module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already imported the *function* object; leave off the `pprint.` reference:

```
output = ', '.join([pprint(p) for p in people_list])
return HttpResponse (output)
```

This will not do what you want still, as it'll print to `sys.stdout`, **not** return a pretty-printed value. Using the `pprint` module is not very suitable for use in a web server environment really.

I'd create a `PrettyPrinter` instance and use it's [`PrettyPrinter.pformat() method`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html#pprint.pformat) to generate output instead:

```
from pprint import PrettyPrinter

pprinter = PrettyPrinter()
output = ', '.join([ pprinter.pformat(p) for p in people_list])
```

You can use [`pprint.pformat()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html#pprint.pformat) too, but it's more efficient to just re-use a single `PrettyPrinter()` object.

Comment: ok I fixed the import. How do I set up PrettyPrinter ? What do I need to customize from the sample above?

Comment: @Prussian: Replace your import with the import I used in my second sample. Add the `pprinter =` line just above where you produce the `output` variable. Replace the `output = ` line with my version.

Comment: Interesting, it gave me this error UnboundLocalError at /patients/display
local variable 'output' referenced before assignment

Comment: :Thanks. That "worked" but it is not displaying anything just a blank screen and an attribute error is listed as the page name (weird). I guess it might be related to my object variables?

Comment: That'd be something else entirely. What *is* `people_list` anyway? A list of Django database results? Then you'd be better of giving the model a good [`__unicode__` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/instances/#unicode) instead.

Comment: Can't you just use `pprint.pformat` instead of creating a `PrettyPrinter` instance?

Comment: @SolomonUcko: you can, but that'll create a new `PrettyPrinter` insteance each time. By creating a single `PrettyPrinter()` instance and reusing that, you avoid the cost.

Comment: That's true, just the answer was slightly confusing. Good point.

Answer (score 3):

`from pprint import pprint` just imports the `pprint` function from the `pprint` module, and you're trying to do `pprint.pprint` on that function.

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint
Traceback (most recent call last):
    pprint.pprint
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'pprint'
```

Just `pprint` will work fine:

```
>>> pprint
<function pprint at 0xb6f40304>
```

To access `PrettyPrinter` and other attributes of `pprint` module you need to import just `pprint` module:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint
<function pprint at 0xb6f40304>
>>> dir(pprint)
['PrettyPrinter', '_StringIO', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '_commajoin', '_id', '_len', '_perfcheck', '_recursion', '_safe_repr', '_sorted', '_sys', '_type', 'isreadable', 'isrecursive', 'pformat', 'pprint', 'saferepr', 'warnings']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have imported pprint then you can use as pprint("")

Import can be done this way..... 
**from pprint import pprint**